# Linear Algebra Image of $A^t$ is equal to the image of $A^t A$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then the image of $A^t$ is the same as $A^tA$.

Comment: you can start trying to relate the kernel of $A$ and the kernel of $A^T$

Answer (score 2):

Here we're working with real scalars.

$\text{Ran}(A^t) = \text{Ker}(A)^\perp$ while $\text{Ran}(A^t A) = \text{Ker}(A^t A)^\perp$.   But since $\|A x\|^2 = x^t A^t A x$, $\text{Ker}(A^t A) = \text{Ker}(A)$.